# I want to create 5 random numbers between 2 numbers and display in my textbox

Tags: c#

Im just learning C# at uni and seem to be struggling to get this random number to out put in a textbox. I havnt learnt a language before this so apologies if its a simple question.

I want to create 5 random numbers, between two different numbers specified by the user. Then print the 5 numbers generated into a textbox to display them.

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        int firstnum = Int32.Parse(txtboxnum.Text);
        int secondnum = Int32.Parse(txtboxnum2.Text);


        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(firstnum, secondnum);

        Int32 loop = 0;
        do
        {
            loop++;
        }
        while (loop > 5);

        string myString = randomNumber.ToString();

       string  txtboxanswer = myString;
```

I would be much appreciative of any suggestions where im going wrong. As i just cant seem to get the answer to appear in my textbox. I know i must be close. I hope :)

Thanks for all help in advance.

Comment: you need all the 5 values in same text box  altogether at a time?

Comment: THis seems like homework, maybe it should have that tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you did not set the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the result.

```
txtBoxName.Text= myString
```

Comment: string  txtboxanswer.Text = myString; This gives me a red line under the txtboxanswer.Text am i missing something else?

Comment: got it. take the string out at the start. Thanks

Comment: @user1735367 I assume that you have a TextBox called txtBoxName

Answer (score 1):

You are close enough. With minimum editing of your code, it should be pretty much like this

```
int firstnum = Int32.Parse(txtboxnum.Text);
    int secondnum = Int32.Parse(txtboxnum2.Text);


    Random random = new Random();


    Int32 loop = 0;
    do
    {
       int randomNumber = random.Next(firstnum, secondnum);
       string myString = randomNumber.ToString();
       TextBox t= new TextBox();
       t.Text=myString; 
       t.Left=0;t.Top=loop * 20;
       this.Controls.Add(t);

       loop++;
    }
    while (loop < 5);
```

For more on adding controls dynamically [check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984255%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: It should be while(loop < 5);

Comment: Also you should put the code for generating new random number inside the loop. For each iteration there should be new generated random number.

Answer (score 1):

by the way, this is how I'd do it

```
        int firstnum = 0;
        int secondnum = 1;
        Random random = new Random();

        int[] randomnums = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < randomnums.Length; i++)
        {
            randomnums[i] = random.Next(firstnum, secondnum);
        }
```

and then you can do something like

```
string myString = randomnums[1].ToString()
```

to get the string representation of a particular number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int a = rand.Next(Min, Max);
    textBox1.Text =  textBox1.Text + string.Format(" {0} ", a.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What's the use of for loop here? You are overwriting last value after every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right track, I think the only thing you are missing is to assign the string to a textbox. Just place another textbox (let's say answertxtbox) and write in the end of your loop the following:

```
answertxtbox.Text += txtboxanswer + ", ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because everyone seems to be answering...

```
 int firstnum = Int32.Parse(txtboxnum.Text);
 int secondnum = Int32.Parse(txtboxnum2.Text);
 Random random = new Random();

 List<int> results = new List<int>();
 for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
 {
     results.Add(random.Next(firstnum, secondnum));
 }

 answertxtbox.Text = String.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll<int, String>(results.ToArray(), Convert.ToString));
```

Note: I wouldn't actually do it this way but it does illustrate that there are many, many ways of solving the same problem.